# Cannot install mitmproxy certificate on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, mitmproxy

In windows cmd, I switched to the folder where the certificate is present and ran this command:

```
certutil.exe -importpfx Root mitmproxy-ca-cert.p12
```

The output was:

```
Enter PFX password:
CertUtil: -importPFX command FAILED: 0x80070056 (WIN32: 86 ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD)
CertUtil: The specified network password is not correct.
```

I had entered a random string of 1234 as my password and got the above error message. What I am doing wrong and how do I fix this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from here [Windows asks for p12 password when installing p12 key generated by openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452301/windows-asks-for-p12-password-when-installing-p12-key-generated-by-openssl).

I used an empty password to resolve the problem. But, I don't know if this would have any negative consequences later.